# Incompatible column types. Previous type Invalid Current type WorkflowEventType

Tags: column, custom-application

I have created my layer using SPMETAL everything works fine , but when I want to update the workflow history column ( Event Type) it throws this error**"Incompatible column types. Previous type Invalid  Current type WorkflowEventType**"
I tried with SPManager / tried with different mapping but no luck.
here I have change the EventType property type to **object** then I able to get the value from Sharepoint , but when I try to save the value it throws error.
here is my generated code

```
  [Microsoft.SharePoint.Linq.ColumnAttribute(Name = "Event", Storage = "_eventType", Required = true, FieldType = "Object")]
    public object  EventType
    {
        get
        {
            return this._eventType;
        }
        set
        {

            if ((value != this._eventType))
            {
                this.OnPropertyChanging("EventType", this._eventType);
                this._eventType = value;
                this.OnPropertyChanged("EventType");
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Did you make any changes after generating your data layer with SPMETAL?

Comment: yes I introduce: marker interface for mapping to my DTOs, after getting error in workflowcommentshistory wrong mapping of event type I changed integer to Text.

Comment: I have checked it with default spmetal generted layer and try to save my comments in history list it throws the same error?? :(